# plotting a histogram: TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a data frame and I need to plot a histogram of a column, but IO keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  

    data = df[['col']]  
    data.info()>>>  
    RangeIndex: 183404 entries, 0 to 183403
    Data columns (total 1 columns):
    col    183404 non-null int64
    dtypes: int64(1)  

    bins = np.arange(-100, 100, 5)  
    plt.hist(data , bins = bins)    
    plt.show()
```

I keep getting the error TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type and I do not know why.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `Tenure_Q2` here?

Comment: Fixed it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plt.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) doesn't want a DataFrame. It wants "(n,) array or sequence of (n,) arrays".

Instead do:

```
plt.hist(data.values, bins=bins)
```

Alternately you could just do this, as `pd.Series` work with `plt.hist`:

```
plt.hist(df['col'], bins=bins)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [DataFrame built in function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) to do this:

```
df.hist('col', bins = 5)
```

Bins might work differently than you're expecting, see the documentation.  It takes an int for the number of bins (default 10)